# Probability of heavy smoker dying?

Tags: probability

A research study involves $20$% heavy smokers, $30$% light smokers and $50$% non-smokers. Light smokers are twice as likely to die than non-smokers but are half as likely to die than heavy smokers. A person has  recently died that was involved in the research study. What is the probability that the person was a heavy smokers?

My answer (is this correct)
$P(A) = 0.20$,  $P(B) = 0.30$    $P(C) = 0.50$

$P(D|A) = \cfrac47, P(D|B) = \cfrac27, P(D|C) = \cfrac17$

Bayes theorem
$$P(A|D) =  \frac{P(A)P(D|A)}{P(D)} = \frac{0.20(\frac{4}{7})}{0.20(\frac{4}{7}) + 0.30(\frac{2}{7}) + 0.50(\frac{1}{7})}$$

Comment: looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

You answer is correct, but there is a small error in you calculation. You only now the ratio between "likelihood of death" not the exact numbers. Observe the difference.

$P(A) = 0.20$,  $P(B) = 0.30$    $P(C) = 0.50$

$P(D|A) = 4a, P(D|B) = 2a, P(D|C) = a$

Bayes theorem
$$P(A|D) =  \frac{P(A)P(D|A)}{P(D)} = \frac{0.20(4a)}{0.20(4a) + 0.30(2a) + 0.50(a)}$$

It gives the same answer in this case.

Comment: yeah i figured later on. thanks